# IIS not including the PDF file in build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

I got a requirement to show the one PDF file on button click. I added that document to the Content folder in the MVC project and added the URL to that button. When I click on the button the PDF opens fine in my local. But When I deploy it to the DEV server, getting 404 error. So I checked the Content folder in the web server, I can't find the PDF file I added. Do I have to change any IIS settings to include that PDF in the build?

Thanks

Comment: Is pdf file included in the project? Open the project/solution in Visual Studio and then right click on the pdf under content folder and click include in project.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is the same as the one documented [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/79094/serve-pdf-fies-in-iis) you'll want to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb742440(v=technet.10)) under "Adding MIME Types to [IIS version]" to ensure that you have pdf enabled among the supported content types.

Comment: I think the issue is related to missing pdf file in the published website rather than missing pdf MIME type

Comment: Right - the theory would be that the linked settings would interfere with the migration of pdf content files to the server. Can you share the steps you performed to migrate your project to the server?